# Is the Amazon Locker Patented?

Tags: process, business-methods, amazon.com

I did an [advanced search](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-adv.htm&r=0&p=1&f=S&l=50&Query=AN/%22Amazon.com%22%20AND%20%28delivery%20OR%20locker%20OR%20distribution%29&d=PTXT) for `AN/"Amazon" AND (delivery OR locker OR distribution)` and could not find a patent for the [Amazon Locker](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200689010). Is it patented? If so, what is the patent number? Is it publicly known if they tried to patent it? If not, why not? Or are they licensing from another patent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend **not** using the USPTO's search site. Google patents is easier to use, more forgiving of poor search strings, now has patents and patent applications from China, Europe and WIPO, and provides access to information besides the patent itself, including assignment history.

The search you did might have found something if you didn't have the ".com" in the search string. The company's actual corporate name has no dot com in it. Putting amazon locker into google patents turns up several documents, including:

A better search would be to use google patents advanced and put Amazon in the assignee field instead.

[US8504653 Amazon](https://www.google.com/patents/US8504653?dq=amazon%20locker&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rappUo6eMYuzigLVnoDgCw&sqi=2&pjf=1&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBQ)

If looking for physical lockers, a quick search did not turn up Amazon patent documents, but others are in that game.

[image]

Comment: The link you gave is for a digital locker. The "locker" I refer to is a physical goods locker.

Comment: I'm using `AN/"Amazon"` now, but still no luck finding the patent.

Comment: That link (which you removed) refers to a Hitachi Patent. Is Amazon licensing from Hitachi?

Comment: So Amazon does NOT have a patent?

Comment: Thanks, I removed it because I was too hasty posting it, sorry. There may be patents out there from Amazon on this topic but I did not see any. Also, if you stick with the USPTO search, they have a completely  separate page for searching published applications. Just because my 5 min. search doesn't find something does not mean it doesn't exist.